# Parsing JSON value in a Snowflake Variant column to multiple columns based on condition

Tags: arrays, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to parse below JSON data in column test_column from table table_a. If the label department has Electrical, dept_1 should be defaulted as 1, if label department has Electronics, dept_2 should be defaulted to 1, and if label department has Chemical, dept_3 should be defaulted to 1.

| test_column |
| --- |
| {"labels": {"department_id": "1","department": ["Electrical","Electronics","Chemical"]}} |
| {"labels": {"department_id": "2","department": ["Electrical"]}} |

I used below query but it is not yielding what i want -

**Query used:**

```
select dept_id, 
case when dept='Electrical' then 1 else NULL end as dep1,
case when dept='Electronics' then 2 else NULL end as dep2,
case when dept='Chemical' then 3 else NULL end as dep3
from(
     SELECT 
         test_column:labels:department_id::varchar as dept_id, 
         array_to_string(test_column:labels:department,',') as dept
     FROM table_a
  );
```

Could you tell me what is going wrong? Am getting NULL for records having all 3 Eletrical, Eletronics, and Chemical.

**Expected result:**

| dept_id | dept_1 | dept_2 | dept_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | NULL | NULL |

Comment: `array_to_string` simply converts the entire array to a single string.  So, if there are multiple values, you will never get those case statements correctly matching a value within the array.  It will only work when there is a single value, which is what you are seeing.

Comment: Is that expected output correct? It seems as if you'd want the first row to be 1, 1, 2, 3 instead of 1, 1, 1, 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options to do this differently.

Option #1: Flatten your array and then re-aggregate back for your case statements:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT parse_json('{"labels": {"department_id": "1","department": ["Electrical","Electronics","Chemical"]}}') as var
)
SELECT  x.var:labels:department_id::integer as dept_id, 
        max(case when y.value::varchar='Electrical' then 1 else NULL end) as dep1,
        max(case when y.value::varchar='Electronics' then 2 else NULL end) as dep2,
        max(case when y.value::varchar='Chemical' then 3 else NULL end) as dep3
FROM x,
lateral flatten (input=>var:labels:department) y
group by 1;
```

Option #2 - since your case statement is just evaluating the presence of a value, you can just look at the array using a `ARRAY_CONTAINS` function to evaluate:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT parse_json('{"labels": {"department_id": "1","department": ["Electrical","Electronics","Chemical"]}}') as var
)
SELECT  x.var:labels:department_id::integer as dept_id, 
        case when array_contains('Electrical'::variant, var:labels:department::array) then 1 else NULL end as dep1,
        case when array_contains('Electronics'::variant, var:labels:department::array) then 2 else NULL end as dep2,
        case when array_contains('Chemical'::variant, var:labels:department::array) then 3 else NULL end as dep3
FROM x;
```

Comment: FYI - Option #2 is likely more efficient from a performance perspective, but you should test them both out against your data.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below query:

```
SELECT 
    test_column:labels:department_id::varchar as dept_id, 
    IFF(ARRAY_CONTAINS('Electrical'::VARIANT, test_column:labels:department), 1, NULL) as DEP_1,
    IFF(ARRAY_CONTAINS('Electronics'::VARIANT, test_column:labels:department), 1, NULL) as DEP_2,
    IFF(ARRAY_CONTAINS('Chemical'::VARIANT, test_column:labels:department), 1, NULL) as DEP_3
FROM table_a;
```